# SQL multiple where clause in Update

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL table with acc_no, ifsc_code, and amount. I want to transfer amount from one account to another checking condition(if both acc_no and ifsc_code of receiver matches).How should I write MySQL query?

Comment: Update atmsystem.account_info set amount=amount+? where ifsc=? and acc_no=?;";    I have written to update receivers account but this code doesnt gives exception when one of the condition doesnot matches

Answer (score 0):

If both conditions ware match means you can use and for both conditions.

```
select * from table where acc_no=value and ifsc_code=value
```